# How service can know when the controller who injected it has destroyed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a books service to search for book.
Most of the time the service, give for example only 20 books.

I want the service to be able to change properties of the books on the screen, after the controller recieve the data.

**For example:**
I have a controller that show list of 20 books (from a search query, and limit properties).

I want that the service will be able to change the books that the controller got, after the controller got the data (realtime change)

```
controller($scope,bookService){
    $scope.data=bookService.getList(query,20)
}

service(function(){
  var dataBindedToController=[]
  return{
    getList:function(query,limit){
       dataBindedToController.push([{name:'book1'},{name:'book2'}])
       return dataBindedToController[dataBindedToController.length-1]
  }
  }
})
```

In the example above every time controller ask for list of books I add the returned data to the service by reference. After that for example if I do in the service: `dataBindedToController[0][2].name='Moshe'`, it will automatically update the controller. the Controller `$scope.data` === `dataBindedToController[0]`

Now the question is: When the controller have destroyed, how the service can now this, and remove the bindedData from it's array?

I want to keep the controller ASAP (as simple as possible).

---

**Another example:**
A working JSFiddle, that use the bind technique to update a counter in a service, after the controller got the data:
https://jsfiddle.net/tLLtn45j/

```
var app=angular.module('app',[])
.controller('a',function($scope,service){
  $scope.data=service
})
.service('service',function($interval){
  var data={counter:3}
  $interval(function(){data.counter++},500)
  return data
})
```

The question is: how the service can now when to stop update the counter, when the controller have been destroyed

Comment: What if, multiple controllers use the service at the same time?

Comment: I will add each controller data to this array: `dataBindedToController`. Then a controller destroy, I will splice the array, to remove the data that not nessecerey any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the scope like this

```
controller($scope,bookService){
    $scope.data=bookService.getList($scope, query,20)
}
```

then save the `$scope` in your service, then attach the event listener there. I'm not sure though if it's a good practice to pass the $scope to the service, and I think it's not

---

you can listen to `$destroy` event

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {

   bookService.destroy($scope.$id);

})
```

you might want to index the `dataBindedToController` with `$scope.$id` so you will know what to remove

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer to not add code to the controller, only to the service. There is a way that the service will know which contoller called him?